# Parallel Julia Graphs Functions Use Only One Core

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, graph-theory

I start Julia 1.8.3 with

```
Julia --threads 50
```

on a machine with 144 CPU cores. It is a single machine, not a cluster.

Then, following the instructions on this [site](https://juliagraphs.org/Graphs.jl/dev/advanced/parallel), I load the `Graphs` package, load the data, and call the parallel version of the betweenness centrality function:

```
using Graphs
import Graphs.Parallel
g = Graphs.loadgraph("/home/x/Graph.lgz")

betweenness_p = Parallel.betweenness_centrality(g)
```

However, when executing the last line, the machine runs the function using one CPU core only. It is a `{114573767, 2210719423} directed simple UInt32 graph`. The openSUSE Leap 15.4 machine has with around 750 GB RAM considerably more RAM than needed to load the graph.

Why does the betweenness function utilize only one CPU core?

Comment: Have you tried with another test multithreaded code to check if the problem is in some setting/permissions or it is specific of the function you want to run?

Comment: Multithreading in Julia generally works on that machine. Executing a `Threads.@threads for` loop does use all the cores specified when starting Julia. The problem appears to be specific to the parallel functions in the Graphs package.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Graphs package. Did you try with --procs 50 ? Maybe the distribution is handled with process